# Capture ScreenShots faster for higher resolution devices without rooting device

Tags: android

I am taking screen-shots or if better put in words I can say I am Creating Bitmap from a view's drawing cache in a loop in my application.

**I am able to take screen-shots at the rate of 10 fps for Samsung galaxy tab 3 which is quite good. But, when I do the same thing on higher resolution devices like Nexus 7 the speed drops to 5 fps.**

I am worried at the level of nexus 10 it may drop to 2 fps which will make my application crippled on bigger devices.

**Can anyone suggest me a way through which this speed can be increased without rooting the device?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

I was using view.getDrawingCache() which is slow process. Instead we can use View.draw(canvas) method.

```
while (running) {
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
                    Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

            v1.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));

            if (bitmap != null) {

                bitmaps.addImage(bitmap);//add to arraylist
            } 
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.err.println(" ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException "
                    + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("EXCEPTION " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

This code may throw array indexOutOfBound exception so I have catched it. It works as a Charm :)